# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'

Tags: python

So I was making a PDF Merger using Python as I found it to be a good project for a beginner like me. I started off with using **PyPDF4** and after all the hard work (not that hard) had been done I ran the program only to be greeted by "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'".
First question up, it DID find the filename that is in the specified directory and it does exist there. How did it find its name but still say it doesn't exist? Second Question, How do I get rid of this :<

## I Use the # thingy to keep the code clean, don't mind if I do!

```
# <------Import Modules-------->
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileMerger
from os import listdir
# <-----------Misc------------->
filedirinput = input("Please enter a directory destination: ")
pdf = (".pdf")
# <-----Merge our Files------------------
manager = PdfFileMerger()# <------------|   PdfFileMerger is now "manager" so that Karens can call it anytime XD
for files in listdir(filedirinput):# <--|  For all the files in our Input Directory
    if files.endswith(pdf):# <-------| Check if file ends with .pdf and move to next step
        manager.append(files)# <--------| Merge all our files in the Directory using Manager (PdfFileMerger)
# <--------Output Time YE!!!--------->
outputname = input("Please enter your desired filename: ")
manager.write(outputname + pdf)
# <-----------Misc------------->
print(f"{outputname + pdf} was generated in {filedirinput}")

# NOTE This part is in development and you currently CANNOT mail somebody
# ALSO, I might turn all of this into a Tkinter GUI program :)

print("Do you want to email this to someone: Y/N")
yn = input("> ")
if yn == "N":
    print("Thank You for Using PyDF Merger :)")
    print("Made By NightMX!")
```

Me getting a Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NrKg.jpg
Have a Good  Day!,

Comment: you should post your code here

Comment: Have you tried providing the absolute path to PdfFileMerger, rather than relative path?

Comment: im using that only

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass complete(absolute) path along with file name to manager.append(files) at line#12. The directory you got at Ln#6 is used to retrieve the list of files, however you have not used this while appending the files at Ln#12

Comment: manager = PdfFileMerger() <br>
for files in listdir(filedirinput): <br>
    if files.endswith(pdf):<br>
        manager.append(filedirinput, 'rb')

Comment: filedirinput will have only path without file name, files parameter will have only file name without path information. Please print the values of these variables to understand better. You need to append these two to form absolute path including file name

Answer (score 0):

@venkat is correct in his answer. `manager.append(files)` does not contain the full path, and therefore cannot merge the files.

For your example, try

```
for files in listdir(filedirinput):
    if files.endswith(pdf):
        manager.append(filedirinput + str("\\") + files)

outputname = input("Please enter your desired filename: ")
merger.write(filedirinput + str("\\") + new_filename)
merger.close()
```